# Windows client - MYSQL server on linux

Tags: mysql, .net, linux

I have a Winforms desktop app that need to read/write data from/to a MYSQL database. The MYSQL server is on a machine that runs on Linux OS. I need to know if a .NET connector is to be used or an ODBC connector?
Also, considering that I do not need remote access to MYSQL server, is a connector sufficient to access the server from the windows desktop? Do I need to do something on the server side? I've been looking around and getting mixed signals, some people said a web service is required while others said no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I need to know if a .NET connector is to be used or an ODBC connector?**

I never connected to MYSQL before, but i think you can use [these](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) data provider or, ODBC too.

**Is a connector sufficient to access the server from the windows desktop?**

Yes. A valid address to your server is all you need to access it, using data providers or ODBC. Of course, your database need to be up and running too.

**Do I need to do something on the server side?**

Just install your MYSQL database.

Maybe this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/camilord/connecting-to-remote-mysql-linux-server-using-visual-C-Sharp/) will help you.

Comment: Will the data provider work even if the server OS is linux? Thanks!!